# Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to get the `display name` and `createdDateTime` of Azure AD Groups by calling MS Graph from PowerShell.

For that, I'm using below PS Script:

```
$Body = @{
    client_id = "app_id"
    client_secret = "secret"
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}

$Connect_Graph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body $Body

$token = $Connect_Graph.access_token

$query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/"
$groups = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token)"} -Uri $query -Method Get).value | Select displayName, createdDateTime
```

It failed with `403 Forbidden`

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At C:\Users\script.ps1:13 char:12
+ $groups = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($to ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I have given permissions for `Group.Read.All` and `Directory.Read.All`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check what type of permissions you granted for  **`Group.Read.All`** and **`Directory.Read.All`**.

- If you are trying to access the API as signed-in user, then you have to use **Delegated** permissions.
- If you are trying to access the API without signed-in user, then you have to use **Application** permissions.

***I executed the same script in my environment and got the same error when I have Delegated permissions without signed-in user like below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error**, I granted **Application permissions** for **`Group.Read.All`** and **`Directory.Read.All`** and executed the below script:

```bash
$Body = @{
    client_id = "app_id"
    client_secret = "secret"
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}
$Connect_Graph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body $Body
$token = $Connect_Graph.access_token
$query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/"
(Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token)"} -Uri $query -Method Get).value | Select displayName, createdDateTime
```

**And I got the results successfully like below:**

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/YoTlhlt.png)]

Comment: Yes, I added Delegated permissions that's the issue! After adding Applications Permissions, I got the results that I wanted.